# The role of "IS" in "What would my family and friends say is the driving force of my life?"

Tags: sentence-meaning, questions, interrogatives

> What would my family and friends say **is** the driving force of my life?

The sentence above, I'm not really familar with this specific construction, especially with the position of **is**.

I guess that means : What is the driving force of my life would my family and friends say?

But how can it be of that position possible?

Comment: Consider: _"My family and friends would say [**what** is the driving force of my life]?"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this sentence -

> My family and friends would say (that) **X** is the driving force of my life.

We don't know what **X** is. So

> My family and friends would say **what** is the driving force of my life.

*My family and friends would say* is the superordinate clause or main clause. The subordinate clause is *what **is** the driving force of my life*

Here in subordinate clause **is** is the main verb. *What (**X**) is the driving force of my life*

Subject - What (**X**)

Verb - is

Predicate - the driving force of my life.

So we form the question this way -

> **What** *would* my family and friends say *is* the driving force of my life?

*My family and friend would say* is the main clause. So notice how the verb *would* is coming at the front of the subject.

To learn more about this, please go through [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/32779/3463). @F.E. has written a fantastic answer there.

Answer (score 2):

> What [would my family and friends say] **is** the driving force of my life?

The meaning of the sentence is:

> Suppose someone asks my family members and my friends: "What **is** the driving force of his life?" What would they reply?

To remodel a bit:

> What would my family and friends say if asked the question of what **constitutes** the driving force of my life?

Another remodeling:

> What **is** the driving force of my life in the view of my family and friends? What would they say, if asked?

Comment: What about this one: If you make it assertive the sentence will be like this - *My family and friends would say (that) X is the driving force of my life.* -> *My family and friends would say **what** is the driving force of my life*. Now make it a question - ***What** would my family and friends would say is the driving force of my life?*

Comment: @Man_From_India - seems nice to me, you might post it as an asnwer!

Comment: I have nothing else to add :( you have already given a good explanation, and Adam also :)

Comment: @Man_From_India You really ought to write an answer post, because the OP is specifically looking for a syntactic explanation for that construction. :)

Answer (score 2):

You got the basic structure correct:

> What is the driving force of my life?

I think  that *"would my friends and family say"* constitutes as adverbial phrase (not sure about the part of speech, here).  It definitely functions like this one would:

> What is the driving force of my life, according to my family?

*"according to my family"* modifies *is* and could be moved to be nearer to it:

> What, according to my family, is the driving force of my life?

Another way we can say *"according to my family"*

> What would my family say is the driving force of my life?